# How to extract network edge attributes list of tuples to dictionary of tuple dictionary pairs(edge labels)?

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I have a network graph with edges and edge attributes. I'm trying to extract edge attributes from the edges using

```
sub_gr.edges(data=True)

edge_labels = list(sub_gr.edges(data=True))
```

```
[(1405394338,
  1367797753,
  {'Email': 'NJOHNSONJOHNSON34@GMAIL.COM',
   'Phone': 5392353776,
   'VIN': '1C3CDZBG9DN5907'}),
 (1405394338, 1354581834, {'Phone': 5392353776}),
 (1405394338,
  1334448011,
  {'Email': 'NJOHNSONJOHNSON34@GMAIL.COM', 'Phone': 5392353776}),
 (1405394338, 1244950426, {'Email': 'NJOHNSONJOHNSON34@GMAIL.COM'}),
 (1354581834, 1367797753, {'Phone': 5392353776}),
 (1354581834, 1334448011, {'Phone': 5392353776}),
 (1334448011,
  1367797753,
  {'Email': 'NJOHNSONJOHNSON34@GMAIL.COM', 'Phone': 5392353776}),
 (1334448011, 1244950426, {'Email': 'NJOHNSONJOHNSON34@GMAIL.COM'}),
 (1367797753, 1244950426, {'Email': 'NJOHNSONJOHNSON34@GMAIL.COM'})]
```

Returned a list of tuple with the nodes and edge attributes.

Now I'm want to convert this to

```
{(1334448011, 1244950426): {'Email': 'NJOHNSONJOHNSON34@GMAIL.COM'},
 (1334448011, 1367797753): {'Email': 'NJOHNSONJOHNSON34@GMAIL.COM',
  'Phone': 5392353776},
 (1354581834, 1334448011): {'Phone': 5392353776},
 (1354581834, 1367797753): {'Phone': 5392353776},
 (1367797753, 1244950426): {'Email': 'NJOHNSONJOHNSON34@GMAIL.COM'},
 (1405394338, 1244950426): {'Email': 'NJOHNSONJOHNSON34@GMAIL.COM'},
 (1405394338, 1334448011): {'Email': 'NJOHNSONJOHNSON34@GMAIL.COM',
  'Phone': 5392353776},
 (1405394338, 1354581834): {'Phone': 5392353776},
 (1405394338, 1367797753): {'Email': 'NJOHNSONJOHNSON34@GMAIL.COM',
  'Phone': 5392353776,
  'VIN': '1C3CDZBG9DN5907'}}
```

Dictionary of tuples as keys and attributes to values.

To use in edge_labels

```
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(sub_gr,pos,edge_labels=edge_labels,font_color='red')
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two good ways to go about this in `networkx`. The first is to make separate labels for each field, and plot them in different colors, like this:

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create the graph from the example edgelist
edges=[(1405394338,
  1367797753,
  {'Email': 'NJOHNSONJOHNSON34@GMAIL.COM',
   'Phone': 5392353776,
   'VIN': '1C3CDZBG9DN5907'}),
 (1405394338, 1354581834, {'Phone': 5392353776}),
 (1405394338,
  1334448011,
  {'Email': 'NJOHNSONJOHNSON34@GMAIL.COM', 'Phone': 5392353776}),
 (1405394338, 1244950426, {'Email': 'NJOHNSONJOHNSON34@GMAIL.COM'}),
 (1354581834, 1367797753, {'Phone': 5392353776}),
 (1354581834, 1334448011, {'Phone': 5392353776}),
 (1334448011,
  1367797753,
  {'Email': 'NJOHNSONJOHNSON34@GMAIL.COM', 'Phone': 5392353776}),
 (1334448011, 1244950426, {'Email': 'NJOHNSONJOHNSON34@GMAIL.COM'}),
 (1367797753, 1244950426, {'Email': 'NJOHNSONJOHNSON34@GMAIL.COM'})]
G=nx.DiGraph(edges)

# Grab the labels individually
labels1=nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'Email')
labels2=nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'Phone')
labels3=nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'VIN')

# Setup the figure and plot it
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
pos=nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G,pos)

# Add each label individually
nx.drawing.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=labels1,font_color='red',label_pos=0.75,rotate=True)
nx.drawing.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=labels2,font_color='blue',label_pos=0.5,rotate=True)
nx.drawing.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=labels3,font_color='green',label_pos=0.25,rotate=True)

# display
plt.show()
```

The figure in this case looks like this:
[image]

The other is to make custom labels, like this:

```py
# Setup the figure and plot it
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
pos=nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G,pos)

custom_labels = {}
for u,v,d in G.edges(data=True):
    L=""
    for att,val in d.items():
        L+=att+":"+str(val)+"\n"
    custom_labels[(u,v)]=L

nx.drawing.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=custom_labels,font_color='red',
                                     rotate=False,horizontalalignment ='left')
```

In this case, the figure looks like this:
[image]

Of course, you can play with the figsize and font parameters to make these prettier. Also, I would personally recommend using yED (https://www.yworks.com/products/yed) or some other graphical interface for this kind of thing. You can use `nx.write_graphml(G, "filename.graphml")` to export to a file yED can read in, then use it's property mapper and layout tools to get things set up. It's tedious if you're looking through a lot of plots, but if you want to make a "final version" figure, it's really a much better tool for the job because it's easy to fine-tune the placement of individual nodes, edges, and labels. (This is how I make 99% of the network figures for my research papers and conferences slides.)

**EDIT** For completeness, I'll put the yED export code and the figure I made for it here:

```py
# Make a copy for export
G_ex=G.copy()

# Add the custom labels we made earlier 
# to the copy graph as an attribute
for u,v in custom_labels:
    G_ex.edges[(u,v)]['label']=custom_labels[(u,v)]

# Convert the attributes to strings to avoid import headaches
for e in G_ex.edges():
    for k,v in G_ex.edges[e].items():
        G_ex.edges[e][k]=str(v)

# Actually do the exporting
nx.write_graphml(G_ex,"test.graphml")
```

I imported the graphml file into yED and played around with it until I got this as the result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the pattern is always the same: the first two elements from `edge_lables` should be the key and the third element is the value then you can use dictionary comprehension.

```
d = {x[:2]: x[2:][0] for x in edge_labels}

{(1405394338, 1367797753): {'Email': 'NJOHNSONJOHNSON34@GMAIL.COM',
  'Phone': 5392353776,
  'VIN': '1C3CDZBG9DN5907'},
 (1405394338, 1354581834): {'Phone': 5392353776},
 (1405394338, 1334448011): {'Email': 'NJOHNSONJOHNSON34@GMAIL.COM',
  'Phone': 5392353776},
 (1405394338, 1244950426): {'Email': 'NJOHNSONJOHNSON34@GMAIL.COM'},
 (1354581834, 1367797753): {'Phone': 5392353776},
 (1354581834, 1334448011): {'Phone': 5392353776},
 (1334448011, 1367797753): {'Email': 'NJOHNSONJOHNSON34@GMAIL.COM',
  'Phone': 5392353776},
 (1334448011, 1244950426): {'Email': 'NJOHNSONJOHNSON34@GMAIL.COM'},
 (1367797753, 1244950426): {'Email': 'NJOHNSONJOHNSON34@GMAIL.COM'}}
```